# sending a value with HttpPost object

Tags: php, android

I would like to send a value to the end of a url.

ex:

if I have `id=1;`, I want to send this id to end of my url (to obtain id) :

> www.example.com/get/id

id values ​​are different. (ex:id=2;id=3;id=4...).

is it possible ? how can I use HttpPost for this Scenario ?

I am using these functions but I always get this message :

> no parametrs was sended !

inside my url :

www.example.com/get/id :

```
function get($id=0){

$id = (int)$id;
if(!$id) exit("no parametrs was sended !");

$trac  = $this->m_general->get('tractions' , array('id' => $id ) , true );



if(!$trac ) $resp = "-1";
else
if($trac->expired != 0  ||   $trac->cradit_end_date < date('Y-m-d'))
{
    $resp = 0;
}else
$resp = 1;

echo json_encode(array('response'=>$resp));

}


function set(){

    $data = $this->input->post('data');
    if(!$data) exit("no parametrs was sended !");


    $message = $data;
    $message = substr($message,7,-6);
    list($qr,$date,$time) = explode("&",$message);

    $insert = array(
    'qr'=>$qr ,
    'date'=>$date ,
    'time'=>$time ,
    'main'=>$message
    );

    $this->m_general->add('qr' , $insert );
```

}

---

```
private void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.url_server_side);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", valueIWantToSend));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.e("Response = ", res);

        isok = 1 ;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        isok = -1 ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        isok = -1 ;
    }
    //Log.e("res", response.toString()) ;
}
```

Comment: It's ok you have to call the function get and pass the id `get($_POST['id']);`

Comment: how can I send id in java code ?

Comment: new BasicNameValuePair("data", valueIWantToSend); "data" is the name of the parameter in this case you should change it with "id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned above your web application expecting GET method to pass variables. In java code you are sending a POST request. You should use GET method to pass data.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/id/YOUR_ID_DATA/data/YOUR_DATA";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

Or send both id, data in a POST request and accept as a POST response from PHP side.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", YOUR_ID_DATA));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", YOUR_DATA));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Then in PHP Side

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
```